# Detect ld flags in m4 files

Tags: linux, macos, ld, autoconf

I have a `.m4` file that appends some flags to the linker, one of which sets the rpath flag. This script was originally written for a GNU version of ld that uses `-rpath=<value>`, however, I'm trying to run the script on OSX, where the version of ld uses `-rpath <value>`. The end result is that I see this in my config.log:

> ld: unknown option: -rpath=path/to/stuff

Is there a way to detect something about how ld expects flags to be passed in from within my `.m4` file so I can output the right format depending on the version available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to detect if linking succeeds with given flag using [AC_LINK_IFELSE](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.63/html_node/Running-the-Linker.html) macro in your script, for example:

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING([for rpath flag style])

saved_cflags="$CFLAGS"
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -Wl,-rpath=."
AC_LINK_IFELSE([AC_LANG_SOURCE([int main(){ return 0;}])],
               [RPATH_FLAG=gnu],
               [RPATH_FLAG=none])
CFLAGS="$saved_cflags"

if test "x$RPATH_FLAG" = "xnone"; then
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -Wl,-rpath,."
AC_LINK_IFELSE([AC_LANG_SOURCE([int main(){ return 0;}])],
               [RPATH_FLAG=llvm],
               [RPATH_FLAG=none])
CFLAGS="$saved_cflags"
fi

AC_MSG_RESULT([$RPATH_FLAG])
```

And set proper flag based on this detection.